# php export data to custom CSV

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am writing a function to export my data to csv.
What I want is every data should be in double quotes.
It was working fine until I notice a problem:

Output is as follows normal data for example

```
"Hello";"1232323";
```

is displaying fine. Only problem comes when there is a space between data

```
"Hello world"
```

it displays with one extra space and one space before and after quotations.

could anyone help me how can i remove this extra space, or what I am doing wrong,

```
   protected function outputCSV($data, $delimeter = ';',$enclosure = " ") {
        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($output, $row,$delimeter, $enclosure);
        }
        fclose($output);
    }

    public function ExportCsv($id)
    {
        if(!$id) return false;

        /* Headers */
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result_file.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");


        /*  get Reiseverlauf Data */
        $rf = $this->getReiseVerlaufByDatasetId($id);
    
        if($rf[0]){
            foreach ($rf as $rv){
                $dataata[] = array('"'.date("d.m.y l", strtotime($rv['date_from'])).'"','"'.date("d.m.y", strtotime($rv['date_to'])).'"','"'.$rv["service"].'"','"'.$rv["location"].'"');
            }
        }
        $this->outputCSV($data, ";" , " " );

        exit ;
    }
```

Comment: Is `$dataata` supposed to be `$data`?

Comment: `$enclosure = " "` should be `$enclosure = ""`

Comment: If you process `$dataata`, then it's adding double quotes, and you don't want that. Also why you use `" "` as `enclosure` instead of double quote as default?

Comment: it gives me this error when i changed enclosure to "" 
fputcsv(): enclosure must be a character

and if I use  '"' this as eclosure it gives me everything in 3 qouted like """Hello"""

Answer (score 0):

You're using space as delimiter.
Also some other minor issues in your code.

Try this code instead:

```php
   protected function outputCSV($data, $delimeter = ';' ,$enclosure = "") {
        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($output, $row, $delimeter, $enclosure);
        }
        fclose($output);
    }

    public function ExportCsv($id)
    {
        if(!$id) return false;

        /* Headers */
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result_file.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");


        /*  get Reiseverlauf Data */
        $rf = $this->getReiseVerlaufByDatasetId($id);
    
        if($rf[0]){
            foreach ($rf as $rv){
                $data[] = array('"'.date("d.m.y l", strtotime($rv['date_from'])).'"','"'.date("d.m.y", strtotime($rv['date_to'])).'"','"'.$rv["service"].'"','"'.$rv["location"].'"');
            }
        }
        $this->outputCSV($data, ";" , "");

        exit ;
    }
```

Comment: it gives me this error when i changed enclosure to "" 
fputcsv(): enclosure must be a character

and if I use  '"' this as eclosure it gives me everything in 3 qouted like """Hello"""

Comment: Ok. What if you use `chr(127)` as delimiter instead?

Comment: it is giving me same result as before 
forexample i have this thing in a line

"18.08.21";"18.08.21"; "Amazon  Test" ;"aaeeeeeeeee";"a";"REG/ESP/Standard/ENG"

everything is working fine until a space comes ex( amazon Test ) 
There is a space before and after double qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

> **Note**:
>
> If an `enclosure` character is contained in a field, it will be escaped by doubling it, unless it is immediately preceded by an `escape_char`.

Since you set `$enclosure = " "`, any unescaped space character is doubled.

If you don't want it adding enclosure characters, because you're wrapping everything in quotes in the caller, use `$enclosure = ""`.

Comment: it gives me this error when i changed enclosure to "" 
fputcsv(): enclosure must be a character

Comment: Then I don't think you can do this with `fputcsv()`. Why do you need to put quotes around all fields? That's not standard CSV format.